# Laravel 5: how to test Jobs which call APIs?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I've been teaching myself how to write test cases, but I'm clueless as to how we can test if a `Job` calls an API (and assert that the API has got the expected response).

Here are snippets of my experimentation...

```
Class SampleJob extends Job
{

    public function handle()
    {
        $request->method('post')->setUrl('/blahblah')->setBody($body);
        //For the sake of convenience, let me just state that
        //$request calls an API call.
        //i.e. If it's successful, you'll get
        //HTTP status 200 and a JSON object
    }
 }


Class SampleJobTest extends TestCase
{
    use DispatchesJobs;

    /** @test */
    public function it_calls_api()
    {
        $data = factory(MockData::class)->create();
        $this->dispatch(new SampleJob($data));

        //assert that the API was called

        //assert that there was an HTTP response - status & JSON
    }
}
```

As the comments mention, would it be possible to assert that the API was called with the expected response?

Any advice will be appreciated.

*EDIT*

When SampleJob is dispatched, the API will be called.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but simply if `handle` is called then you call api itself too ?

Comment: @AnarBayramov Exactly!

Comment: so you can mock handle method and check if it is called ?

Comment: @Hiroki when you say assert the the API was called, you want to confirm that it was handled by the api middleware? or is the 200 status suffecient? would you elaborate more so I can update my answer below.

Comment: @HamzaMohamed Hi! It is enough to get the 200 status (or 422, depending on the input). No middleware is involved in this test.

Comment: @Hiroki Hi :) .. so this means that you would consider the below as an answer? or did I miss something?

Comment: @HamzaMohamed Unfortunately, I can't modify the result from `SampleJob::dispatch($data);`. The handle function of the class can't return the response directly.

Comment: I believe I wrote it unclear and I have deleted that line .. what I meant is that you can alter the $response as you wish ,, whatever can initiate the response and also match your code. I have updated the below to be more clearer.

Comment: @HamzaMohamed I'm not sure if it's really possible to get `$response` from a job dispatched in that way... by the way, apparently we need to use `dispatch` helper, instead of dispatch function as a static function. Otherwise, it results in `Error: Call to protected method` (I updated this question)

Comment: @AnarBayramov Could you elaborate on "mocking handle method"?

Comment: @Hiroki seems that error for not calling the class `DispatchesJobs`, I have included that below.

Answer (score 4):

Testing the Json API job is a bit tricky, as you have to test if it was queue'd, dispatches, then you get to know if you are going to receiving a response and if it is the expected one.

To keep it simple and as well useful; I separated the functions into 3 tests (dispatch, queue and result) so you can test each process and you can expand even more to test the

**Queues:** [Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues)

1. which Queue was the job pushedOn?
2. how many times?
3. sent or prevented?

**Buses:** [Bus command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/bus)

1. sent or prevented?

which can you find more [reference here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mocking#queue-fake) on the Queue testing and same for the command Bus if you are interested on the same page.

This is the test class:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue; // includes the fake method
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus;  // includes the fake method
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs; // for the Queue
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatcher; // for the Bus
use App\Jobs\APIjob as Job; // your job goes here


class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    use DispatchesJobs;
    /**
     * Setup the test environment. //  to  make the environment as a usual Laravel application which includes the helpers functions.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setup(){
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
     * A basic dispatch example.
     * 
     * @return void
     * @test
     */
    public function it_dispatches(){
        Bus::fake(); // faking the Bus command
        $job = new Job;
        Bus::dispatch($job);
        Bus::assertDispatched(Job::class, 1);
    }

    /**
     * A basic queue example.
     * 
     * @return void
     * @test
     */
    public function it_queues(){
        Queue::fake(); // faking Queue using the facade
        $job = new Job;
        Queue::push($job); // manually pushing the job to the Queue
        $this->dispatch($job);
        Queue::assertPushed(Job::class, 1);
    }

    /**
     * A basic receive example.
     *
     * @return void
     * @test
     */
    public function it_recieves_api(){
        $response =  $this->get('/APIroute'); // change this to match the route which you will receive the Json API from.

        $response->assertStatus(200) //
                 ->assertJsonFragment([ // using Fragment if partial, you can remove the word Fragment for full match
                        [
                        'id' => 1,
                        "name" => "Emely Jones",
                        "email" => "sgleichner@example.com",
                        "created_at" => "2018-03-05 16:36:14",
                        "updated_at" => "2018-03-05 16:36:14",
                        ],
                    ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this ends up `$response` being null.